# Plotting continuous versus categorical variable in a bar chart using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am a newbie to base R. I have gone through similar issues here but didn't get it resolved. I am using the code:

```
ggplot(combined_Attributes, aes(x = factor(CatAge), y = Total_Expenditure, 
fill = "#0073C2FF" + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge"))) + geom_text(aes(label = CatAge))
```

[image]

I do not want a text written on the plot but the categories and as reference. Struggling with this.

Comment: Not sure if I understood correctly, but if you do not want the text you could just remove the geom_text. Or what text do you want to be plotted? and could you share some lines of your dataframe?

Comment: The categories are on the x-axis, you need them in the plot as well?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, whether you are looking for something like this, but here I used mpg demo data-frame from the tidyverse and calculated the frequency of each model prepared by the manufacturer and plotted as bar plot.

```r
library(tidyverse)

data(mpg)
mpg
#> # A tibble: 234 x 11
#>    manufacturer model    displ  year   cyl trans   drv     cty   hwy fl    class
#>    <chr>        <chr>    <dbl> <int> <int> <chr>   <chr> <int> <int> <chr> <chr>
#>  1 audi         a4         1.8  1999     4 auto(l~ f        18    29 p     comp~
#>  2 audi         a4         1.8  1999     4 manual~ f        21    29 p     comp~
#>  3 audi         a4         2    2008     4 manual~ f        20    31 p     comp~
#>  4 audi         a4         2    2008     4 auto(a~ f        21    30 p     comp~
#>  5 audi         a4         2.8  1999     6 auto(l~ f        16    26 p     comp~
#>  6 audi         a4         2.8  1999     6 manual~ f        18    26 p     comp~
#>  7 audi         a4         3.1  2008     6 auto(a~ f        18    27 p     comp~
#>  8 audi         a4 quat~   1.8  1999     4 manual~ 4        18    26 p     comp~
#>  9 audi         a4 quat~   1.8  1999     4 auto(l~ 4        16    25 p     comp~
#> 10 audi         a4 quat~   2    2008     4 manual~ 4        20    28 p     comp~
#> # ... with 224 more rows

ggplot(mpg, aes(x = manufacturer, y = frequency(model),
                fill = model)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45))
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>